# Can a 48v electric bike battery be charged from a 4v or 5v Son 28 hub dynamo?

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, inverter, dynamo

I want to ride an electric bicycle over long distances, including hills.  I only want the motor for steep ascents.  I am trying to stay off-grid as much as I can.  So I would like to recharge the bike's 48v 17amp-hour battery without stopping in motels to recharge from their wall sockets.

I will have a Schmidt Son 28 hub dynamo on the front wheel.  It produces 4v to 5v at the speeds I am likely to be riding.

https://nabendynamo.de/en/tech/son-28-vs-sondelux/

Here is a graph of the amperage the dynamo produces.  To a layman it is as opaque as blood.

http://nightrider.xf.cz/son28_en.htm

Will I be able to keep my battery charged with this dynamo?

Comment: Would solar panels help much?

Comment: The way most batteries work you'll need a voltage > 48V to charge a 48V battery.

Comment: Here is one person's experiment with a solar charger: https://www.outdoorgearlab.com/expert-advice/how-to-make-a-solar-powered-electric-bike

Comment: Powering a LED is peanuts in energy compared to the elephant going up hill, it is not enough.

Comment: Why can't you use the bike's motor as a generator? Doesn't the bike already support regeneration? If so it is already being recharged when you are descending.

Comment: why can't you charge from the traction motor?

Comment: What speed range do you expect to travel i? This is omportant to answering the question. | You will need a converter to step the voltage up to ~= 48V. As others have said - it is highly likely that the main motor can be used to charge regeneratively. | The dynamo makes maybe 5 Watts out. at medium speeds - less at slower speeds.  Hill assist of maybe 250 Watts would be nice. Even less is useful. 
250/5 = 50:1. You can get very roughly 10 seconds of assist per 500s = 8+ minutes of riding. That's useful but not really enough. Look into motor regeneration.

Comment: A modest solar charger - 5 or 10 Watts - would be useful as it is at work to some extent much of the day.

Comment: No it won't do anything useful. Even if you step the dynamo output up to 48V it'll only supply a few W, enough for lights. Use the main traction motor as a dynamo going dewnhill, it's about 100x more powerful.

Answer (score 3):

Likely not. That hub only generates 3watts of power. It would take very long time to charge a 48 V, 17 Ah battery at that rate.

Someone else check my hack math, but your batteries would take 272 hours of charging at 3 watts, to go from a discharged to charged battery.

Comment: Maths confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not even close. While you can step up the voltage and charge the battery, the power put out by the dynamo is far from enough. It puts out about 3 Watts on average, while the average 48V bike battery has about 600 Wh. This means it'll take 200 hours (almost 10 full days) of continuous cycling to get a single charge, assuming that there are no losses. Given that the motor controller will also consume some power when idle, as will your charging circuit, it's more than likely that the battery will actually drain while you're attempting to charge it with that dynamo.

Solar panels might work. You'll need very large ones, however, like the ones you see on rooftops. If you can carry two or three of those, you might be able to charge your bike using solar power while you're taking a (multi-hour) break.

Comment: Get flexible solar cells and make a sail!